# Route does not work with like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a problem with routes. How to use root

I need you to identify the url and redirect to post show

site.com/string

root to: 'post#show#:id', id:: string

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
get '/:id', to: 'post#show'
```

Docs about [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: @WelitonJosé: You might want to consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem. That's a way to say thank you on stackoverflow.